# how to create text file in window service

Tags: c#

I have an XML file

```
<config>
<ServiceName>autorunquery</ServiceName>
<DBConnection>
    <server>servername</server>
    <user>xyz</user>
    <password>klM#2bs</password>
<initialcatelog>TEST</initialcatelog>

</DBConnection>
<Log>
    <logfilename>d:\testlogfile.txt</logfilename>
</Log>
<Frequency>
    <value>10</value>
    <unit>minute</unit>
</Frequency>
<CheckQuery>select * from credit_debit1 where station='Corporate'</CheckQuery>
<Queries total="3">
    <Query id="1">Update credit_debit1 set station='xxx' where id=2</Query>
<Query id="2">Update credit_debit1 set station='xxx' where id=4</Query>
<Query id="3">Update credit_debit1 set station='xxx' where id=9</Query>

</Queries>
</config>




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Service1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = null;
        string path = null;
        FileStream fs = null;
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Interval = 10000;
            timer1.Start();
            logfile("start service");


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop();
            logfile("stop service");

        }
        private void logfile(string content)
        {

            try
            {
                reader = new XmlTextReader("queryconfig.xml");//xml file name which is in current directory
                if (reader.ReadToFollowing("logfilename"))
                {
                    path = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
                fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.Write(content);
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sw.Write(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
                if (sw != null)
                    sw.Close();
                if (fs != null)
                    fs.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that the file is not created.

Comment: Not answers to your question as such but just some general advice. You shouldn't call `sw.Write` in your exception handler unless you're sure that `sw` is created, in general it's a bad idea to try to log the error when the logging fails :). And if you're only going to use `reader` and `sw` in the logging method, you could just make them local variables instead of member variables. And if you do that, you could possibly use `using` rather than the finally statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening probably because you are using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. It was not designed to work with a windows service.
Change your timer component to System.Timers.Timer. This class is suitable for Windows Services.

Comment: Ah yes, Forms.Timer requires message loop that windowless windows service lacks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose service identity has no rights to write to HD. 
Check system event log for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not created you would very likely get an exception which would appear in event log and your service would terminate as you do not handle any exceptions.

My guess would be that the file *is* created but not in the location that you expect. To check that either use a hard-coded absolute path or use Process Explorer to find the working folder of your service.

A simple technique for debugging scenarios like this one is to use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` for putting out debug information and then start [Debug View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals to receive and display the trace messages.